# Ping Pong in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a ping pong game. At the moment I got the ball moving and both paddles moving when keys pressed. But the ball does not bounce off the paddles. There is code to bounce off player2 paddle but it does not seem to work. It's a lot of code I know. Can you help me find out what is wrong?

```js
"use strict";
// Variables

var c = document.getElementById("sCanvas");
var ctx = sCanvas.getContext("2d");
var cHeight = sCanvas.height;
var cWidth = sCanvas.width;

//Objects

//create paddle object

class Paddle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.colour = "red";
    this.xPoss = x;
    this.yPoss = y;
    this.width = 12;
    this.height = 60;
    this.speed = 3;
  }

  drawMe() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
    ctx.fillRect(this.xPoss, this.yPoss, this.width, this.height);
  }
} // end paddle object

//create the sphere object
class Sphere {
  constructor() {
    this.radius = (10);
    this.colour = "blue";
    this.xPos = 65; //Math.random() * cWidth;
    this.yPos = 100; //Math.random() * cHeight;
    this.speedY = 5; //* Math.random();
    this.speedX = 5; //* Math.random();
  }

  drawMe() {
      //method to draw itself
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
      ctx.fill();

    }
    //method to move itself
  moveMe() {
      this.yPos += this.speedY;
      this.xPos += this.speedX;

      //bounce off the bottom wall
      if (this.yPos > cHeight - this.radius) {
        this.speedY = -this.speedY;

      } //bounce off the top wall
      else if (this.yPos < 0 + this.radius) {
        this.speedY = -this.speedY;
      }

      //stop ball if hit right side
      if (this.xPos > cWidth) {
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;

      }
      //bounce off player 2 paddle
      else if (this.xPos > player2.xPoss && (this.yPos > player2.yPoss && this.yPos < (player2.yPoss + player2.height))) {
        this.speedX = -this.speedX;

      }

    }
    //end moveMe function
} // end Sphere object

//******************
// create game objects
//******************
var ball = new Sphere();
var player1 = new Paddle(10, 150);
var player2 = new Paddle(580, 150);

//*********************
// Deal with key presses
// **********************

var keysDown = []; //empty array to store which keys are being held down


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keysDown[event.keyCode] = true; //store the code for the key being pressed
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});

function checkKeys() {

  if (keysDown[90]) {
    if (player1.yPoss > 0) {
      player1.yPoss = -player1.speed; //z
    }
  }

  if (keysDown[88]) {
    if (player1.yPoss < (cHeight - player1.height)) {
      player1.yPoss += player1.speed; //x
    }
  }

  if (keysDown[190]) {
    if (player2.yPoss > 0) {
      player2.yPoss = -player2.speed; //"."
    }
  }

  if (keysDown[188]) {
    if (player2.yPoss < (cHeight - player2.height)) {
      player2.yPoss += player2.speed; //","
    }
  }

}

// your 2 new sets of code here for 2 more keys for player 2





//*********************
// Make the score board
// **********************



//*********************
// launch the ball from the centre, left and right, on space bar
// **********************


function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
  ball.drawMe();
  ball.moveMe();
  player1.drawMe();
  player2.drawMe();
  checkKeys();

}

render(); //set the animation and drawing on canvas going
```

```html
<canvas id="sCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border: solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'd suggest `console.log`ing out the conditions which indicate a collision occurred. This will tell you which one(s) aren't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a simple hit box and detector and drawing the boxes in black to illustrate.  Changed xPoss, yPoss to xPos, yPos for consistency.  Changed `= -` to `-=` on the paddle movement (was snapping to top when moving up).  Changed `class` and methods to JavaScript functions and prototype methods.

This should be enough to go on to see the how JavaScript does objects and how to do a simple hit detection.  This isn't the only way to create objects but it is close to what you were trying to do.

*update*

Made some changes to hit/collision detection. Can now hit ball from bottom and top of paddle.

```js
"use strict";
// Variables

var c = document.getElementById("sCanvas");
var ctx = sCanvas.getContext("2d");
var cHeight = sCanvas.height;
var cWidth = sCanvas.width;

//Objects

//create paddle object

function Paddle(x, y) {

  this.colour = "red";
  this.xPos = x;
  this.yPos = y;
  this.width = 12;
  this.height = 60;
  this.speed = 3;

}

Paddle.prototype.drawMe = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
  ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.width, this.height);
}; // end paddle object


/***** BEGIN COLLISION DECTECTION FUNCTIONS *****/
// optimized collision of boxes - Does a hit b?
function hit(a, b) {
  
  // Return immediately when the objects aren't touching.
  if (
    a.x2 < b.x || // a.right is before b.left
    b.x2 < a.x || // b.right is before a.left
    a.y2 < b.y || // a.bottom is before b.top
    b.y2 < a.y    // b.bottom is before a.top
  ) {
    return false;
  }

  // The objects are touching. It is a hit or collision.
  return true;
}

// does a hit the top of b?
function hitTop(a, b) {
  return (a.y2 > b.y && a.y < b.y) ? true : false;
}

// does a hit the bottom of b?
function hitBottom(a, b) {
  return (a.y < b.y2 && a.y2 > b.y2) ? true : false;
}

// Creates an obect of x, y, x2, y2 for hit detection.
function hitObj(obj) {

  var h = {x:0, y:0, x2:0, y2:0};
    
  if (obj.radius) {
    h.x = obj.xPos - obj.radius;
    h.x2 = obj.xPos + obj.radius;
    h.y = obj.yPos - obj.radius;
    h.y2 = obj.yPos + obj.radius;
  } else {
    h.x = obj.xPos;
    h.x2 = obj.xPos + obj.width | (obj.radius * 2);
    h.y = obj.yPos;
    h.y2 = obj.yPos + obj.height | (obj.radius * 2);
  }
    
  // draw hit box - uncomment to see hit detection
  /*
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeRect(h.x, h.y, h.x2 - h.x, h.y2 - h.y);
  ctx.restore();
  */

  return h;
}
/***** END COLLISION DETECTION FUNCTIONS *****/

//create the sphere object
function Sphere() {

  this.radius = (10);
  this.colour = "blue";
  this.xPos = 25; //Math.random() * cWidth;
  this.yPos = 5; //Math.random() * cHeight;
  this.speedY = 5; //* Math.random();
  this.speedX = 5; //* Math.random();
}

Sphere.prototype.drawMe = function() {
  //method to draw itself
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
  ctx.fill();
};

Sphere.prototype.moveMe = function() {
  //method to move itself

  // save start position. change back to start
  // position when there's a hit so we don't
  // get stuck in an object.
  var pos = {
    x: this.xPos,
    y: this.yPos
  };

  // move
  this.yPos += this.speedY;
  this.xPos += this.speedX;

  //bounce off the bottom wall
  if (this.yPos > cHeight - this.radius) {
    this.yPos = pos.y;
    this.speedY = -this.speedY;


  } //bounce off the top wall
  else if (this.yPos < 0 + this.radius) {
    this.yPos = pos.y;
    this.speedY = -this.speedY;
  }
/*
  //stop ball if hit right side
  if (this.xPos > cWidth) {
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;

  }
*/
  // Bounce off left and right sides.
  if ((this.xPos+this.radius) >= cWidth || this.xPos <= 0) {
    this.xPos = pos.x;
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
  }
  
  //bounce off player paddle
  else {
    
    var pad1 = hitObj(player1);
    var pad2 = hitObj(player2);
    var ball = hitObj(this);
        
    if (hit(ball, pad2)) {
      // hit player2
      this.xPos = pos.x;
      this.speedX *= -1;
      // if the ball travels down and hits top OR
      // if the ball travels up and hits bottom then bounce back
      if (
        (this.speedY > 0 && hitTop(ball, pad2)) ||    
        (this.speedY < 0 && hitBottom(ball, pad2))
      ) {
        this.yPos = pos.y;
        this.speedY *= -1;
      }
    } else if (hit(ball, pad1)) {
      // hit player1
      this.xPos = pos.x;
      this.speedX *= -1;
      // if the ball travels down and hits top OR
      // if the ball travels up and hits bottom then bounce back
      if (
        (this.speedY > 0 && hitTop(ball, pad1)) ||    
        (this.speedY < 0 && hitBottom(ball, pad1))
      ) {
        this.yPos = pos.y;
        this.speedY *= -1;
      }
    }
  }
};
//end moveMe function


//******************
// create game objects
//******************
var ball = new Sphere();
var player1 = new Paddle(10, 150);
var player2 = new Paddle(580, 150);

//*********************
// Deal with key presses
// **********************

var keysDown = []; //empty array to store which keys are being held down


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keysDown[event.keyCode] = true; //store the code for the key being pressed
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});

function checkKeys() {

  if (keysDown[90]) {
    if (player1.yPos > 0) {
      player1.yPos -= player1.speed; //z

    }
  }

  if (keysDown[88]) {
    if (player1.yPos < (cHeight - player1.height)) {
      player1.yPos += player1.speed; //x
    }
  }

  if (keysDown[190]) {
    if (player2.yPos > 0) {
      player2.yPos -= player2.speed; //"."
    }
  }

  if (keysDown[188]) {
    if (player2.yPos < (cHeight - player2.height)) {
      player2.yPos += player2.speed; //","
    }
  }

}

// your 2 new sets of code here for 2 more keys for player 2





//*********************
// Make the score board
// **********************



//*********************
// launch the ball from the centre, left and right, on space bar
// **********************


function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
  ball.drawMe();
  ball.moveMe();
  player1.drawMe();
  player2.drawMe();
  checkKeys();

}

render(); //set the animation and drawing on canvas going
```

```css
#sCanvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="sCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border: solid;"></canvas>
```